# Sybase SQL coalesce with alias

Tags: sql, alias, sybase, coalesce

Trying to get the first non-null value of two fields and whichever picked, set as an alias, an example is below:

```
SELECT a, b, c, coalesce(d, e) AS foo FROM table
GROUP BY a, foo
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

When running this query, it is saying invalid column name foo? I can't see what I am doing wrong here, can anyone see?

Comment: Depending on the DB engine you cannot use an alias in the `group by` clause. Use `group by a, coalesce(d, e)`

Comment: @juergend oh really? I am using Sybase, I'll look into this. Thanks :)

Comment: @juergend - That worked a treat! Thank you! :D